# How can I set equal max height of bootstrap 4 cards regardless of their content?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let book of webService.books_list | async">
      <div class="card h-30 text-white bg-light text-dark mb-3">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ book.imgm }}" alt="Card image top" alt="Responsive image" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ book.title }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{ book.blurb }}</p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/books', book._id]" style="cursor: pointer">View Reviews</a>[enter image description here][1]
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `max-height` CSS attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height

Comment: I tried the proposed solution above, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change card height class. `h-30` to `h-100`

```
 <div class="container" style="margin-top:30px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let book of webService.books_list | async">
          <div class="card h-100 text-white bg-light text-dark mb-3">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ book.imgm }}" alt="Card image top" alt="Responsive image" class="img-fluid">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{ book.title }}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{ book.blurb }}</p>
              <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/books', book._id]" style="cursor: pointer">View Reviews</a>[enter image description here][1]
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this..

```css
.height_equal{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let book of webService.books_list | async">
      <div class="card h-30 text-white bg-light text-dark mb-3 height_equal">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ book.imgm }}" alt="Card image top" alt="Responsive image" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ book.title }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum is simplyLorem ipsum is simplyLorem ipsum is simplyLorem ipsum is simplyLorem ipsum is simplyLorem ipsum is simplyLorem ipsum is simplyLorem ipsum is simplyLorem ipsum is simply</p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/books', book._id]" style="cursor: pointer">View Reviews</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let book of webService.books_list | async">
      <div class="card h-30 text-white bg-light text-dark mb-3 height_equal">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ book.imgm }}" alt="Card image top" alt="Responsive image" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ book.title }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum is simplyLorem ipsum is simplyLorem ipsum is simplyLorem ipsum is simply</p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/books', book._id]" style="cursor: pointer">View Reviews</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```